# The type or namespace name 'SteeltoeWebApplication' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, steeltoe

Following the examples in Steeltoe Workshop:
https://docs.steeltoe.io/guides/get-to-know-steeltoe/index.html

Everything works fine until I get to the part about "Adding a cloud connector with SQL":
https://docs.steeltoe.io/guides/get-to-know-steeltoe/exercise3.html?tabs=visual-studio%2CVisual-Studio-LocalDB

Getting the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SteeltoeWebApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WebApplication1 zzzz\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Controllers\TodoItemsController.cs 3   Active
```

What could be missing?  Is it some kind of Nuget package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a typo in the guide. That namespace is internal to the project, so if you follow the directions exactly you should use `WebApplication1` instead